# The touchpad doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad

I've tried to install the ubuntu on a Acer E-15, but the touchpad doesn't work in the installation process. After installed I've tried to install a lot of packages and it still doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Sorry about the English and thanks.

Comment: Does the touchpad work when you boot from the live USB?

Comment: No. I've installed using a mouse

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: can you run `xinput list` and edit your question with the output? thanks